# I can't install eyeD3 0.7.5 into Python in windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, anaconda, eyed3

could you help me with that. I can't manage to install this plugin. I tried:
1) install it through pip
2) through setup.py in win console
3) through anaconda3 but still no.
4) I searched about it in web and here, but insructions are made to older versions.
5) and also through the installation page of eyeD3.

Could you guide me how should I do this? Maybe I'm doing something wrong. For first: should I use for this Python 2.7.9 or can it be Anaconda3

Comment: Make your working directory = directory in which you have setup.py and then run `python setup.py install`

Comment: what now? http://img42.com/collection/XEnDY

Comment: This has to be run in cmd not in python command line

Comment: http://img42.com/plDYe Ho do i need to change this path form anaconda to python installation folder?

Comment: The command and the directory are correct but there is some syntax error in the amazon.py file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this file is only written for Python 2 but you are using Python 3. You should use Anaconda (vs. Anaconda3), or create a Python 2 environment with conda with `conda create -n py2 anaconda python=2` and activate it with `activate py2`.

Comment: the latest version is available in Python 3